# Can I re-file an old tax return to get a refund of monies paid incorrectly in a previous year?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction

Let's say I screwed up and didn't claim all the deductions that I could have in a previous tax year.

Can I file a new tax return for that year which is corrected, then claim the difference between what I actually paid and what I should have paid as a refund? Is that what an "ammended" return is?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can file an amended tax return to correct the deductions that you did not claim when you originally filed. The [IRS has more information](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/make-a-mistake-amend-your-tax-return) about when to amend and when not to amend tax returns.