# How do I file an amended tax return if I overpaid last year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, amended-tax-return

I just found out that I overpaid my taxes by a significant amount last year.

I suppose I need to file an "amended return" in order to get my money back.

The problem is that if I just fill out the new return, it will show what I should have paid, not what I did pay. How do I enter what I paid, so I can get back the difference? I looked in the "Payments" section of the 1040 and nothing listed is "amount you already paid", except withholding but this is not withholding.

Comment: Follow the IRS link in [this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/75809/10997) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A [1040X](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040x.pdf) is the form and instructions you need.

Don't worry you can rescind the $3 presidential campaign contribution for both you and a spouse.